# Is there any reason not to use const even if you can?

Tags: object-oriented, c++

I recently had a discussion where we argued if it is a good idea to make everything const if possible.

The argument did go like that: If I expose an internal part of the class by returning a non-const reference to it, I should not make that getter const even if it is possible.

For example:

```
  class Foo
  {
     std::unique_ptr<int> bar;

  public:
     Foo()
        : bar{std::make_unique<int>(10)}
     {
     }

     int& getBar() const // <-- we argued about that const here
     {
        return *bar;
     }
  };

  int main()
  {
     const auto foo = Foo{};
     foo.getBar()++;
  }
```

The code from above only works because the `int` is not stored within the memory of `Foo` itself. If I would replace the `unique_ptr` with a normal `int` but keep the public interface of the class the same the compiler will output an error:

```
  class Foo
  {
     int bar;

  public:
     Foo()
        : bar{10}
     {
     }

     int& getBar() const
     {
        // error: binding reference of type 'int&' to 'const int' discards qualifiers
        return bar;
     }
  };

  int main()
  {
     const auto foo = Foo{};
     foo.getBar()++;
  }
```

Is it a good idea to intentionally make a getter function non-const if it exposes something internal of the class as a non-const reference?

Comment: Why would you const something and then increment it?

Comment: Consider the advice from the C++ FAQ on const correctness: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness

Answer (score 9):

A class's interface needs to protect its internal state so that its invariants cannot be violated by outside users. (Within reason, of course. C++ makes it impossible to protect against all modifications.)

An implicit invariant of a const object is that its logical state (whatever that is - the definition of logical state for a class is up to its author, and may differ from simply the values of its bits) cannot change.

So a const function that allows the user to modify the logical state is a bad idea, since it makes it easy to break the invariant,.

Thus the question of whether `getBar()` should be const comes down to whether the value behind the pointer is part of the logical state of the object or not. Perhaps in the real code it is a back reference to some manager object that created this object (not likely for a unique_ptr, but it could be in other cases). In that case, returning a non-const reference from a const member function would be fine.

But in the case of a unique_ptr, it's more likely that the value behind the pointer is actually part of the logical state, and as such returning a non-const reference from a const function is a bad idea.

Comment: I would go further and say returning a non-const reference to the object's internal state is a bad idea whether the getter is const or not.